# Can I setup a task to sign off disconnected users?

Tags: windows, windows-10

So we're using the Windows parental controls stuff to manage accounts for the kids in the house, but they sometimes will just hit Win+L to lock their account when they're finished playing their games (leaving the games running). Is there some way to check occasionally, outside of a user profile, if certain profiles are signed on and inactive and then sign them off? We wouldn't want to sign off every inactive account though because sometimes the adults have legit stuff going on in the background.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a solution, not quite what I had in mind, but it covers my needs.

I created a scheduled task that runs on workstation lock, and had it point to a batch file like so:

```
If %username% == bemat c:\logoff.exe
If %username% == crmat c:\logoff.exe
```

Simple enough, no? Unfortunately that logoff.exe is a custom exe I made with [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/) because `shutdown /l` refused to work after the profile locked. I also tried [PsShutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) but the user accounts in question are limited users and so that wouldn't work either.

For the record the AutoIt script for logoff.exe is just `Shutdown(4)`[*](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Shutdown.htm). I'm sure someone who knows actual programming could create a smaller exe with C++ or something (AutoIt exe's start at about 850kb) but the only semi-compilable coding I know is AutoIt.